# Cakephp function in model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I develop a website using cakephp. But the response time is too slow. So, I want to implement fat model and skinny controller.

But i got

> Call to a member function fashionpage() on a non-object

when calling fashionpage function in controller.

I have Home model(relationship: Home hasMany Cart)

My controller:

```
public function fashionlist() {
        $user = $this->Auth->user('id');

        $counter = $this->Home->fashionpage($user);
        $this->set(compact('user', 'counter'));
    }
```

My model:

```
public function fashionpage($user = null) {
        return $this->Home->Cart->find('count', array('conditions'=>
                                                   array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$user))));
      }
```

can anyone please help me.

Comment: fashionpage function is in Home Model or in Cart Model?

Comment: in home model @arilia

Comment: and fashionlist function is in HomesController?

Comment: yes yes. in homesCOntroller @arilia

Comment: From the error it's obvious you haven't loaded the `Home` model. Try via `$this->loadModel('Home');` or `$uses =array('Home');`. And do @arilia fix

Comment: @lp1051 if he is in HomesController he doesen't need to load Home model

Comment: The error says it clearly, `$this->Home` is not an object. Perhaps cake 1.x or some wrong case in filename/dir? That's why I asked to try to load the model manually and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your model. In fact when you are in your Model file `$this` is the Model (Home in your case), so no need to do `$this->Home->Cart`, but just `$this->Cart`

so not

```
public function fashionpage($user = null) {
        return $this->Home->Cart->find('count', array('conditions'=>
                                                   array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$user))));
      }
```

but

```
public function fashionpage($user = null) {
        return $this->Cart->find('count', array('conditions'=>
                                                   array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$user))));
      }
```

Comment: when you ask 'fashionpage function is in Home Model or in Cart Model? ', i try put that function in cart model. and remove the model name as: 'public function fashionpage($user = null) { 
  return $this->find('count', array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$user)));
      }'

and now it run successfully. thanks for the idea..hehe

Comment: there's something wrong if it works the way you did. If you do that then in your HomesController you have to do `$this->Home->Cart->fashionpage($user);`

Comment: may be your association "Home hasMany Cart" is not working properly .Do check that also.

Answer (score 0):

You must call it with persistent object I think

Comment: what did u means by persistent object ya?

Comment: $this->model('modelname');